# I'm trying to install Swift for Windows, and I almost have it except when I try to run a file. How can I fix?

Tags: swift, linux

I followed the directions [here](https://developerinsider.co/install-apple-swift-on-windows-10-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/), and did everything according to letter except instead of `swift-3.0.1-RELEASE-ubuntu14.04.tar.gz`, I got `swift-3.1.1-RELEASE-ubuntu14.04.tar.gz`. I can do everything except run my program.

When I try to run, I get:

`./helloworld`

> error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.52: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried `sudo apt-get install libicu52`

But I get

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Unable to locate package libicu52
> ```

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/722075/no-installation-candidate-for-libicu52-on-15-10. Seems strange that this is being done on windows, but the required library is for Linux...the world is changing

Comment: its part of the new update mentioned here http://www.developerinsider.in/step-vise-guide-to-enable-windows-10s-ubuntu-bash-shell-windows-subsystem-for-linux/ on the W10 Anniversary Edition

Comment: Reviewing first posts, had to re-read that you was using apt-get in windows a few times.